# Unable to use svDialogs without attaching to search path

Tags: r

I need to obtain user input from the `svDialogs` R package, e.g. using `svDialogs::dlgInput()`. However, attempting to do this without attaching the package with `library()` or `require()` gives an error:

```
svDialogs::dlgInput("Example")  
Error in svDialogs::dlgInput("Example") : attempt to apply non-function
```

The following works fine:

```
library(svDialogs)
svDialogs::dlgInput("Example")
```

Why might this be, and what might be a way around it? I have the current CRAN version of the package (0.9.57).

## Update

I have tried installing previous versions of `svDialogs`, as well as comparing my code with the source code from the `cgam` package, which depends on `svDialogs`. Currently the entire `svDialogs` package is imported in my NAMESPACE, which is how it is used in `cgam`. But I still get the same error unless I first run `library(svDialogs)`. Any tips?

## Update 2

I also imported the entire `svGUI` package in my NAMESPACE, with no luck.

> sessionInfo() R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252
>   LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252
>   [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
>   LC_NUMERIC=C
>   [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1] svDialogs_0.9-57 svGUI_0.9-55
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] compiler_3.4.3
>   tools_3.4.3